# Queue worker freezes unexpectedly and requires restart work work again

Tags: php, queue, worker, beanstalkd, pheanstalk

I have 3 beanstalkd queues and each have its own worker. The workers are written in php and I am not using any framework. To work with the queues I am using pheanstalk to work with the queue.

For some reason the workers suddenly stop working without any error and do not process the jobs in the queue. Once I restart the workers they start working for the next couple of days and the same cycle repeats. Can some one please help me understand on what could be the issue?

My worker

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Pheanstalk\Pheanstalk;


function function_name()
{
  $log_file = './log/error.log';
  $tube_name = 'current_tube_name';
  $memoryLimit = 128;
  $dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__);
  $dotenv->load();
  $beanstalkd_host = $_ENV['BEANSTALKD_HOST'];
  $beanstalkd_port = $_ENV['BEANSTALKD_PORT'];

  while (true) {
    try {
        $pheanstalk = Pheanstalk::create($beanstalkd_host);
        $pheanstalk->watch($tube_name)->ignore('default');
    }
    catch(\Exception $exception) {
        $error_message = "CRITICAL|" . __FILE__ . "|" . __LINE__ . "|" . "Failed to initiate queue worker; could not connect to beanstalkd.Error {$exception->getMessage()}";
        error_log($error_message, 3, $log_file);
        exit;
    }

    $job = $pheanstalk->reserve(10);
    if (!$job) {
        sleep(5);
        continue; //move on to next iteration
    }

    $job_in_queue = $job->getData();//outputting the message
    $job_pay_load = json_decode($job_in_queue, true);
    if(is_array($job_pay_load) == false) {
        $job_pay_load = json_decode(unserialize($job_in_queue), true);
    }

    if (is_null($job_pay_load) || !is_array($job_pay_load) || count($job_pay_load) === 0 || !is_countable($job_pay_load)) {
        $error_message = "CRITICAL|" . __FILE__ . "|" . __LINE__ . "|" . "Job payload structure is not correct. Data: " . print_r($jobPayload, true);
        error_log($error_message, 3, $log_file);
        $pheanstalk->bury($job);
        $job = null;
        $job_pay_load = null;
        continue;
    }

    //do the actual process

    $payload = array(
        'key1' => $val1,
        'key2' => $val2
    );

    $next_tube_name = 'second_tube';
    $json_payload = json_encode($payload);
    $pheanstalk
        ->useTube($next_tube_name)
        ->put($json_payload);

    $pheanstalk->delete($job);

    $job = null;
    $json_payload = null;
    $job_pay_load = [];
    $job_in_queue = null;

    gc_collect_cycles();

    if((memory_get_usage() / 1024 / 1024) >= $memoryLimit) {
        $error_message = "We ran out of memory, restarting... in file ".__FILE__." on line" . __LINE__;
        error_log($error_message, 3, $log_file);
        exit;
    }
  }
 }

 function_name();
```

Answer (score 1):

Beyond looking at the logs and seeing how the script itself is run, or run after it has exited - one thing does come to mind.

You do have a memory-use check, but the [memory_get_usage](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php) function doesn't tell the whole story - there is an optional parameter, `bool $real_usage` which can be set to true. This gets the total amount that has been allocated - as opposed to what is being currently used by PHP.

Since you are checking in this code for memory-usage > 128MB, I'd think that you also have a default PHP setting of `memory_limit` also set at `128M` - but if the amount of memory the script is using is already past that amount, it would have likely **already** failed and exited. Depending on the amount of work you are actually doing, I'd reduce that `$memoryLimit = 128;` down to say 3/4s of the amount - say no more than *92* (megabytes).

Putting in a max-jobs count of how many loops are allowed before it will restart itself would be another way to avoid any potential memory leaks from bringing things down.

Another potential cause is failing to handle a connection issue with the daemon itself - if the `reserve`, or other calls via the Pheanstalk library to Beanstalkd failed.

Ultimately, you have to make sure that the script is restarted automatically if you do deliberately - or accidentally - exit when you don't want to actually stop. How you do that depends on how you start the script running in the first place - and also the version of the OS you are running (as that dictates what tools may be available, such as an `systemd` unit script).

Additional (temporary) logging of (almost) every action and the wider system status would help narrow down where things may be going wrong. Info such as the memory used, number of jobs already processed and how busy the wider system is can all provide useful information.

Comment: Thank you very much for the update. Though my issue has not fully resolved it has improved a lot and your comments helped me in arriving at the root cause. The first step was to log as much information as possible about the worker and then start fixing issues from there.